# How to select and append div to another on select

Tags: html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

Please I need help with this. Here is what I want to achieve. On select of
the select option, each select option on select will append a div out and on select of the same div, it will hide back. And the name of the select value or option will show by the side which is the left side 2column div is defined on each append To. Here is my code sample DEMO [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/innodigita/9Lcq40su/60/)

Here is my HTML CODE.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row col-md-10">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend float-right">
        <label class="font-weight-bold input-group-text" for="Attributes">Attributes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-input col-md-8">
      <select class="my-select w-100 selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" id="attribute_select">
        <option disabled>Nothing Selected</option>
        <option value="size"> Size </option>
        <option value="fabric"> Fabric </option>
        <option value="Shoe"> Shoes </option>
        <option value="boys"> Boys </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 p-3">
    <small>Choose the attributes of this product and then input values of each attribute</small>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="row col-md-10" id="attribute_show">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend float-right">
          <label class="font-weight-bold input-group-text " for="Attributes"><span class="change-me">Items</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="select-input col-md-8">
        <select class="my-select w-100 selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3">
          <option value="0" selected>Nothing Selected</option>
          <option value="1"> XXL </option>
          <option value="2"> XL </option>
          <option value="3">S</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="attribute_append"></div>

</div>
```

**HERE IS MY CSS CODE**. Here I have set the div to display none so that on select it will show and on deselect hide.

```
.select-input button {
  background-color: #aa1876 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#attribute_show {
  display: non;
}
```

HERE IS JQUERY CODE. I have set the jQuery bootstrap-select code here, and the jQuery code for the select option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
      $(function() {
        $(".my-select").selectpicker();
      });
    
    //SELECT CODE
    
      $("#attribute_select").on("change", function() {
        var attrName = $("#attribute_select").val();
        var attriValue = `<label class="font-weight-bold input-group-text" for="Attributes">${attrName}</label>`;
    
        $("#attribute_show").clone().appendTo("#attribute_append");
        $(".change-me").replaceWith(attriValue);
        $("#attribute_show").show();
    
      });
      
      
    });
```

I have been working on this, I will really appreciate it if this is gotten rightly thank you for helping out. Please if you don't understand my code do well to refer to this link https://jsfiddle.net/innodigita/9Lcq40su/60/ to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

I have made some amendment to your code. I'm not sure if this is what you wanted based on your requirements. Below is the attached fiddle you can refer
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/c9mLfnx1/)

**JS**

```
$("#attribute_select").on('changed.bs.select', function(e, clickedIndex, 
isSelected, previousValue) {

var selectedD = $(this).find('option').eq(clickedIndex).text();

if (isSelected) {
  var el = $("#attribute_show").clone();
  var newAttr = '#attribute_show' + count; 
  var html = $(el).appendTo("#attribute_append");
  $(html).removeAttr('id').attr('id', newAttr); // give the cloned div a new ID
  $(html).find(".change-me").text(selectedD);
  count++;
        $(html).find('select.my-select1').selectpicker(); //I have give a new class to 
  //the second selectpicker so that it will not initialize for the first time. It will be initialized after it is cloned.
        
  } else {
  var selectedItems = $(this).val(); //array of selected items from selectpicker

        //check if each cloned item exist in the selectedItems array, if not exist, remove the div
  $('#attribute_append').find('span.change-me').each(function(i, e) {
    //var item = $.trim($(e).text().toLowerCase());
      var item = $(e).text().toLowerCase().trim();
    if (jQuery.inArray(item, selectedItems) == -1) {
      $(e).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
    }
  })
}
});
```

I have put some explanation inside the fiddle for better understanding. Feel free to comment/edit if you find mistakes or bugs. I believe others might have a better or other ways of doing it.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I actually wanted I have searched all over the web including YouTube, but I have not been able to find a result of this, but now you just put a smile on my face again thanks a lot, more knowledge to your understanding.

Comment: Am still trying to make it work at my local machine, because I didn't understand "bs.select" what is what? And previousValue was not called in the code. Please help out for it to work on my local machine. Trim function is showing me depreciated what do I do please for it to work on my local machine thank you.

Comment: @Innocent hi sorry for the late reply. `bs.select` is a built in class name for the boostrap-select library. So instead of giving new class to the select, i just use the predefined class. If u inspect you will see the class name. As for the $.trim function you can try replace with String.trim(). This function is to remove all the whitespace.

Comment: @Innocent I have edited the code for the trim function.